# Google Analytics 4 - Free form Table report, is there a way to wrap text in table's column or extend the column width?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, google-analytics-4

In Google Analytics 4 - Free form exploration report I have selected Table as visualization.
Now after I add my custom dimensions and metric, one of my columns(Custom Dimension 9) can have the text length up to 75 characters.
This column when added to the free form report, values are not getting wrapped and it shows value with  ... at the end,not the full text.

Is there a way to **wrap the column data or extend the column width** in Table visualization ?

[image: Table Exploration Free Form]

Comment: I guess it is possible to hack it. I can think of some kind of a bookmarklet with js code that would resize the columns' width to make the table look readable. Unfortunately that's above my skill level.

Answer (score 3):

As of February 2023, I still can't find a way to do this, but here is a pretty easy workaround.

1. Go to the Export icon and select Google Sheets. That opens a Google Sheets page that says "Would you like to import the data?"
2. Click the "Import Data" button.  After a few seconds your data will open in a Google Sheet
3. Now you can resize the columns in Google Sheets and see the entire text in each column

[image]